# OnCreateOptionsMenu() not called in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an app which got one activity with 2 fragments placed horizontally.

In my activity I inflated menu using `onCreateOptionsMenu()` using which I am able to display actionbar options menu. But when I try to update the action bar  menu items from one of my fragment, the `onCreateoptionsmenu()` is not called. So, I'm not able to update the action bar options menu.

The code in my activity is as below:

**myActivity.java**

```
package com.andr.androidtablelist;

import java.io.IOException;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.andr.fragments.ListLeftFragment;
import com.andr.utils.DBHelper;

      public class TabletActivity extends Activity {
    ActionBar actionBar = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        DBHelper dbhelper;
        dbhelper = new DBHelper(this);
        try {
            dbhelper.createDatabase();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tablet);
        actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.master, ListLeftFragment.newInstance()).commit();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.tablet, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            Toast.makeText(
                    getApplicationContext(),
                    "Back Stack Count::"
                            + getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            if (getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() == 1) {
                actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
            }
            if (getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 1) {
                getFragmentManager().popBackStack();

            }
            return true;

        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
      // http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html
```

**myFragment.java**

```
      package com.andr.fragments;


import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SearchView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.andr.androidtablelist.R;
import com.andr.helper.LazyHelper;

   public class ListLeftFragment extends Fragment{
    private static ListLeftFragment listFragment = null;

    public static ListLeftFragment newInstance(){
        listFragment = new ListLeftFragment();      
        return listFragment;
    }

     @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    }

     @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         View v =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_listlayout, container,false);
         getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();
         ListView lv = (ListView)v.findViewById(R.id.lview);
         String[] values = new String[] { "Android", "iPhone", "WindowsMobile",
                    "Blackberry", "WebOS", "Ubuntu", "Windows7", "Max OS X",
                    "Linux", "OS/2", "Ubuntu", "Windows7", "Max OS X", "Linux",
                    "OS/2", "Ubuntu", "Windows7", "Max OS X", "Linux", "OS/2",
                    "Android", "iPhone", "WindowsMobile" };
         getActivity().getActionBar().setTitle("LeftList");

          ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
         LazyHelper lHelper = new LazyHelper(getActivity());
         list = lHelper.getLazyDetials();

           /* for (int i = 0; i < values.length; ++i) {
              list.add(values[i]);
            }
            final StableArrayAdapter adapter = new StableArrayAdapter(getActivity(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);*/
            LeftListAdapter lAdapter = new LeftListAdapter(getActivity(),list);
            lv.setAdapter(lAdapter);
            lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
            {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                        int pos, long arg3) {
                    final String clickedData = (String)arg0.getItemAtPosition(pos);
                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                    bundle.putString("clickedItemName", clickedData);
                    Fragment detailFragment = DetailFormRightFragment.newInstance();
                    detailFragment.setArguments(bundle);
                    getActivity().getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.details, detailFragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
                }

            }
                    );
         return v;
    }


     @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
        getActivity().getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.search, menu);
        SearchView searchView=(SearchView)menu.findItem(R.id.search);
        searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(true);
    } 

     @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

         super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
         return false;
    }


     @Override
    public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
         super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
        /*MenuItem item;
        menu.clear();
        getActivity().getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.search, menu);
        SearchView searchView=(SearchView)menu.findItem(R.id.search);
        searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(true);*/
    }

     private class StableArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

            HashMap<String, Integer> mIdMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

            public StableArrayAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
                List<String> objects) {
              super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
              for (int i = 0; i < objects.size(); ++i) {
                mIdMap.put(objects.get(i), i);
              }
            }

            @Override
            public long getItemId(int position) {
              String item = getItem(position);
              return mIdMap.get(item);
            }

            @Override
            public boolean hasStableIds() {
              return true;
            }

          }

     private class LeftListAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements OnClickListener {
         private Context mcontext;
         ArrayList<String> listData;
         private  LayoutInflater inflater=null;
         public LeftListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> listItems) {
              mcontext=context;
              listData=listItems;
              inflater = (LayoutInflater)mcontext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
         }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return listData.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int arg0) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup arg2) {
            // create a ViewHolder reference
            View vi=view;
            if(vi==null){
                vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item, null);
            }
            TextView text=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.text);
            text.setText(listData.get(position));
            vi.setOnClickListener(this);
            return vi;
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View vi) {
            TextView text=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.text);
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("clickedItemName", text.getText().toString());
            Fragment detailFragment = DetailFormRightFragment.newInstance();
            detailFragment.setArguments(bundle);
            getActivity().getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.details, detailFragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();          
        }

     }
   }
```

Answer (score 337, accepted):

In your fragment's `onCreateView()` method, you need to call `setHasOptionsMenu(true)` to tell the host activity that your fragment has menu options that it wants to add.

Comment: I made the change,but app crashes with 11-27 01:55:34.468: E/AndroidRuntime(12294): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl cannot be cast to android.widget.SearchView

Comment: yeah I found the issue . forgot to add getActionView() for searchView.

Comment: Also you have to use the void type for onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) the Boolean type won't work

Comment: If you are using `Toolbar` in your Activity's layout, make sure that you call `setSupportActionBar(your_toolbar)` in your Activity. Otherwise `setHasOptionsMenu` has no effect.

Answer (score 32):

If you are using a **theme** that does **not** support ActionBar, then OnCreateOptionsMenu() will not be called automatically, even you wrote all Java codes properly.

You can open AndroidManifest.xml, change the value of **android:theme** to "@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar", or any other themes that support ActionBar.

Comment: i am using toolbar from support library and Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar as theme and i am facing the same problem...no options menu displayed..plz help

Comment: i solved it by calling `toolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.menu_custom);`

Comment: Just call setSupportActionBar(mToolbar) in your activity and onCreateOptionsMenu in Fragments will be called automatically.

Answer (score 14):

Also, make sure that the Toolbar instance you're passing to

```
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

in your Activity is not `null`, because you won't get an exception if it is indeed `null` and you will lose a couple of hours like I did.

I used [ButterKnife](http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/) to bind the views, but accidentally placed `setSupportActionBar(toolbar)` before I actually made the call to `ButterKnife.bind()`

Comment: Haris, you are awesome.  Thank you for sharing this!  I had this exact problem because I'm using Kotlin and many times you don't have to do findViewById, etc... to get the view you need.

Answer (score 13):

this worked for me

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.sample, null);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For those who have the NoActionBar theme such as:
`Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar` the solution is as follows:

##### Kotlin version

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    setupToolbar()
    
}

private fun setupToolbar() {
    setHasOptionsMenu(true)
    // The other option is using val toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolvar) 
    // and add as parameter instead of the binding option
    (activity as AppCompatActivity).setSupportActionBar(binding.toolbar) 
    (activity as AppCompatActivity).supportActionBar?.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false)
}

override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu, inflater: MenuInflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater)
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.my_menu, menu)
}


override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
    return when (item.itemId) {
        R.id.menu_item_1
            //TODO: implement something here for option 1
            true
        }
        R.id.menu_item_2 -> {
            //TODO: implement something here for option 2
            true
        }
        else -> super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Simply tell the host activity that your fragment has options menu in its constructor.</strike>

public YourFragment() {setHasOptionsMenu(true);}

Although it worked for me, it is discouraged as noted in comment from @aldorain

> Applications should generally not implement a constructor. The first
>   place application code can run where the fragment is ready to be used
>   is in onAttach(Activity), the point where the fragment is actually
>   associated with its activity.

So put setHasOptionsMenu(true) in onCreateView() or onAttach() instead.

Comment: You shouldnt write your own constructors for custom fragments

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html tl;dr 'Applications should generally not implement a [Fragment] constructor.'

Answer (score 1):

I you have a theme that doesn't provide you an AppBar by default and you are using a toolbar view to provide this feature instead, DON'T FORGET TO call setSupportActionBar(toolbar) in the onCreate() method of the activity that hosts your fragments.

After that call setHasOptionsMenu(true) in your onCreate() fragment method.

:)

Answer (score 1):

When using the Navigation Architecture Component the action bar is not set so it needs  to be done manually:

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated( @NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState ) {
    NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController( view );

    AppBarConfiguration appBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder( R.id.nav_1, R.id.nav_2, R.id.nav_3 ).build();

    Toolbar toolbar = view.findViewById( R.id.toolbar );
    ((AppCompatActivity) requireActivity()).setSupportActionBar( toolbar );
    CollapsingToolbarLayout collapsingToolbarLayout = view.findViewById( R.id.collapsing_toolbar );

    NavigationUI.setupWithNavController( collapsingToolbarLayout, toolbar, navController, appBarConfiguration );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This one will have diminishing returns as time marches on. In my case it was an androidX dependency on androidx.fragment:fragment:1.3.0-alpha06 which had [this bug](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/180255554)

simply updating that to a stable version resolved the issue.

Answer (score -2):

Set `setHasOptionsMenu(true)` in `onCreateView()` method in fragment.

```
@Override

 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) 
 {
    Viewroot=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_client_requestfragment,container,false);
  hideKeyboard();
    getemail = getArguments().getString("email_id");
    Log.e("email_id from activity",getemail);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    return root;
}
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. Please don't just post uncommented and badly formatted code-only answers as this does not explain what exactly was the problem described in the question. Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for some general tips on what constitutes a good answer.